# Traduction de « personal online data (stores) » dont l'acronyme serait préférablement homonyme d'un nom commun évocateur (POD) en contexte ?

Tags: vocabulaire, traduction, informatique, homonymes, acronymes

Différents acteurs prennent position sur les manières de pallier les carences d'Internet ([structures des GAFA](https://www.lapresse.ca/international/etats-unis/201903/08/01-5217543-elizabeth-warren-veut-demanteler-facebook-amazon-et-google.php), [éducation et esprit critique](https://www.lapresse.ca/techno/internet/201903/12/01-5217901-internet-un-pionnier-du-web-prone-leducation-pour-contrer-les-abus.php) etc.). L'un d'eux dirige un projet ([*Solid*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid_(web_decentralization_project))) de décentralisation de l'information dont l'objectif semble être de physiquement dissocier les données personnelles des structures qui les accueillent et de mettre les premières sous le contrôle de leurs vrais propriétaires, soit les utilisateurs. Un [site](https://solid.inrupt.com/how-it-works) directement associé au développement du produit parle de *Solid POD* et par le truchement de l'article Wikipédia on comprend *Social Linked Data* / *personal online data (stores)*. L'[article](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid_(projet_de_web_d%C3%A9centralis%C3%A9)) en français parle de « données liées » qu'on associe aisément à la première partie de *Solid (POD)*. L'acronyme *POD* est lui-même homonyme d'un mot commun, le [*pod*](https://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/anglais-francais/pod/602758) ayant plusieurs sens.

---

- Comment traduit-on *personal online data store(s)* ?
- Est-on capable de présenter la traduction sous forme d'un acronyme
  évocateur (en étant par exemple homonyme d'un nom commun comme *pod*
  l'est) en omettant un minimum de termes (POD semble omettre le
  « store(s) ») ?

Comment: Pour info, le verbe *pallier* est transitif: on pallie un problème (sans utiliser à) ;)

Answer (score 3):

Nous pouvons traduire *personal online data store(s)* par :

> Centre de stockage de données personnelles en ligne

Je ne connais pas de traduction sous forme d'acronyme, cependant il existe l'expression imagée de « cloud » – autrement dit « nuage de données ».

***Pour aller plus loin :*** Un sigle français très connu et utilisé, lié aux données personnelles en ligne est **RGPD** :

> Règlement général sur la protection des données

Comment: Dans l'hypothèse ou le serveur en question est directement chez l'utilisateur nous parlerons plutôt de *Serveur(s) de stockage*. Je pense en effet qu'un *Centre de stockage* s'oppose à l'idée de *décentralisation* d'un projet.

Comment: Lorsque l'on parle de stockage de données, celles-ci ne peuvent qu'être des données informatiques dans le contexte donné (voir le tag ***informatique*** associé à la question), je ne vois donc pas le problème à l’appeler de la sorte.

Answer (score 0):

Uniquement en ce qui a trait à la deuxième partie de la question :

> CADENAS / **Ca**psule **d'é**léments **n**ominatifs **as**sociés (à l'utilisateur).

En homonyme avec le [cadenas](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/cadenas).